# Read ExtJS message from ajax store

Tags: extjs4

I have an ExtJS store with an ajax proxy and json reader:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '...',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount',
            messageProperty: 'message',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
    ...
```

This is what I get from the server:

```
data: [...]
message: "I want to read this string after the store is loaded"
success: true
totalCount: x
```

Now I want to access the 'message' when the store is loaded - where do I get it? I looked a lot but I can't find a place to hook in? The only listener in the proxy is exception, that doesn't really help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use store [`load`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load) event:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  listeners: {
    'load': function(store, records, successful, operation) {
      alert(operation.resultSet.message);
    }
  },
  proxy: {
  // ...
```

**UPDATE**

It appears that documentation for load event is wrong. The correct list of arguments is `(store, records, successful)` (**no operation argument**). Therefore the solution above wouldn't work.

However there is reader's [`rawData`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-property-rawData) property which can help:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  listeners: {
    'load': function(store, records, successful) {
      alert(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData.message);
    }
  },
  proxy: {
  // ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the load listeners of course, but I didn't know the `resultSet` in operation. But anyway the operation object just contains the store listener methods (I have beforeload and load) and when I try to access resultSet it is undefined. I use ExtJS 4.0.2a. Any idea? Your solution would be perfect - if it would work in my project :) What version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: @Marc, weirdly but it appears that operation argument is not passed into load event handler (But docs say it should be passed). However I've found another solution. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My answer applies to ExtJs 4.1.x. I spent some time reading the code and it seems that one way to do this is to provide a callback in the store beforeload event instead of handling the load event. The callback is passed the operation object which will contain the original request parameters and in case of success it will contain the response object and the data (parsed) under the resultSet property.

Answer (score 0):

In other case:

```
myStore.load({
   callback : function(object, response, success) {
    // on error response: success = false
    if(!success) {
        // i don't remember de correct path to get "message" or "responseText"
        console.log(response.response.responseText);
    } else {
         ... 
    }
});
```

Cya!

Answer (score 0):

I get the message in the following way although I load manually and do not use events here:

```
var initData = Ext.create('My.data.SomeAjaxStore');

initData.load(function(records, operation, success) {
    if (!success || operation.hasException()) {
    // Here is your message from server
    // In case of HTTP error you get:
    //  {
    //    status: 404,
    //    statusText: "Not Found"
    //  }
    var error = operation.getError();
    Ext.log({msg:[Ext.getClassName(me), ": Command failure: ", error].join(""), level:"error"});
}
```